# lively load js and css on the head using append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

for certain reason, I load css and scripts on my head tag using "append" e.g.

```
$("head").append('<script type="application/javascript" src="core/js/main.js"></script>');
```

I'm pulling the html contents asynchronously ("ajax way") and due to contents have specific styles and script functions needed thats why i load the script and css along with it.

here's my code (refer below)

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'page_loader.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    data : { page_name : 'test' },
    type: 'get',
    beforeSend : function(){
        //show a spinner
        $("#spinner").show();
    },
    success : function(data){
        //before load contents, load the css first
        $("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="core/css/main.css" />');
        //load the pulled html contents to the div that has an id of ajax_page
        $("#ajax_page").html(data);
        //then load the script on the head
        $("head").append('<script type="application/javascript" src="core/js/main.js"></script>');
        //hide the spinner
        $("#spinner").hide();
    }
});
```

everything works fine, however I don't want the script and link to be duplicated or multiplied every content load as you can see I'm using append so every time the ajax function called, the script and css that has appended on the head tag is also duplicated (assume the ajax function is called twice or more) so now what I want is to prevent it, is there a way I called load it up once? or is it okay to load it multiple times (ajax run more than once)?

PS: im trying to do like putting an ID on the link and script so that I could check if it did exist, if it is, then don't load, else, load it. So it is valid to put ID on the link tag or script tag?

Comment: Yes it is valid to put an `id` attribute on a `<link/>` or `<script>` tag and then you can use that to see if it has already been added.

Comment: @scunliffe: good. anyway is it cross browser?

Comment: yes, setting an `id` on any element will work cross browser.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery` has the `getScript` function for JS files which you can use.

**Description:** Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

```
jQuery.getScript( 
    url, 
    function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {

    });
```

**Reading Material:**

[`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Answer (score 1):

I can't verify if ID is allowed on `link` or `script` tag, however You could target elements by `href` attribute.

```
if ($('link[href="core/css/main.css"]').length == 0) {
    $("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="core/css/main.css" />');
}
```